# Splitting long lines in bash with numbering

Tags: regex, bash, text, sed

I'm trying to write script that partition very long text (one line) to multiple lines. The requirement is that every line must have prefixes with numbering. I tried using `sed` but I have problem with numbering matches. My code:

```
 sed -e "s/.\{4\}/part = &\\
 /g"
```

Input:

```
AAAAAAAAABBBBBBBAAAAAAABBBBBBB
```

Output:

```
part = AAAA
part = AAAA
part = ABBB
part = BBBB
part = AAAA
part = AAAB
part = BBBB
BB
```

Expected:

```
part1 = AAAA
part2 = AAAA
part3 = ABBB
part4 = BBBB
part5 = AAAA
part6 = AAAB
part7 = BBBB
part8 = BB
```

Additional problem is the last part that is not labeled. Is it possible to do it with sed? Or maybe any other shell tools?

Comment: This might help with GNU sed: `tr -d '\n' < file | sed -e "s/.\{1,4\}/part = &\n/g" | cat -n`

Comment: or without `sed`: `tr -d '\n' <file | while read -r -N 4 x || [ -n "$x" ] ; do echo "part$((++c)) = $x"; done`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "hard" part of that, actually splitting the input into lines, is the job that `fold` exists to do:

```
$ echo 'AAAAAAAAABBBBBBBAAAAAAABBBBBBB' |
    fold -w 4 | awk '{print "part" NR " = " $0}'
part1 = AAAA
part2 = AAAA
part3 = ABBB
part4 = BBBB
part5 = AAAA
part6 = AAAB
part7 = BBBB
part8 = BB
```

Using `fold` will make your life easier if/when your requirements change to, say, try to only split at blanks.

Comment: Thanks! `fold` command did the trick! In fact I used while loop after pipe because that is more friendly for me than awk syntax but I think that is the correct answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Definitely do NOT use a pipe to while loop instead of awk, it only [arguably] **looks** more friendly but it's fraught with issues. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 for some of those issues.

Comment: @glennjackman For this yes but when you next want to try to fold at blanks... Also, `-o` isn't POSIX so YMMV with grep versions.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU awk:

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){print "part" i,"=",$i}}' FPAT='.{1,4}' file
```

Output:

```
part1 = AAAA
part2 = AAAA
part3 = ABBB
part4 = BBBB
part5 = AAAA
part6 = AAAB
part7 = BBBB
part8 = BB
```

From `man awk`:

> `FPAT`:        A regular expression describing the contents of the fields in a record.  When set, gawk parses the input into fields, where the fields match the
> regular expression, instead of using the value of FS as the field separator.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler `gnu awk` solution:

```
s='AAAAAAAAABBBBBBBAAAAAAABBBBBBB'
awk -v RS='[^\n]{1,4}' 'RT{print "part" NR, "=", RT}' <<< "$s"
```

```
part1 = AAAA
part2 = AAAA
part3 = ABBB
part4 = BBBB
part5 = AAAA
part6 = AAAB
part7 = BBBB
part8 = BB
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU tools:

```sh
echo "$str" | grep -oE '.{,4}' | nl -s ' = ' | sed -E 's/^ +/part/'
```

```
part1 = AAAA
part2 = AAAA
part3 = ABBB
part4 = BBBB
part5 = AAAA
part6 = AAAB
part7 = BBBB
part8 = BB
```

Answer (score 1):

Another GNU awk, using builtin variable `RT`:

```
$ echo AAAAAAAAABBBBBBBAAAAAAABBBBBBB | 
awk -v RS=".{1,4}" '{printf "%spart%d = %s",(++i>1?ORS:""),i,RT}'
```

Sample output:

```
part1 = AAAA
part2 = AAAA
...
part8 = BB
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `=` in the replacement string of `s` command is just a literal `=` character, not a line number. This problem could be solved in pure `sed` using 3 `sed` commands in a pipeline like that:

```
line='AAAAAAAAABBBBBBBAAAAAAABBBBBBB'

echo "$line"                  |
sed 's/.\{4\}/&\n/g; s/\n$//' |
sed =                         |
sed 'N; s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/part\1 = \2/'
```

which outputs

```
part1 = AAAA
part2 = AAAA
part3 = ABBB
part4 = BBBB
part5 = AAAA
part6 = AAAB
part7 = BBBB
part8 = BB
```